# MySQL DBMS Views Processing

Tags: php, mysql, database, view, database-performance

I understand MySQL views' usage, algorithms, advantage and disadvantage .. etc.

The only thing that I can't understand is How does MySQL DBMS  process the views and update the view's data?

**For example:-**

We have three tables T1, T2 & T3 .. and We have a view called V1 which collects data from the three table, and a query called Q1 which select some data from V1

- **Assumption #1 (All is executed at once, the View first then the Query):**

  Q1 is executed, so V1 is updated first then the result returns.
- **Assumption #2 (The view is updated after any transaction is done on
  the related tables)**

  Insertion or Deletion transaction is executed on T2, V1 is updated, and anytime Q1 is executed the result returns from V1 (without updating V1, as in this case it's supposed to be updated all the times).

These are my assumptions, Can anybody clear this point for me, How does DBMS handle views?

Thank you so much

Comment: A View is basically a query. So each time you use a view you are actually executing the View query

Comment: Unless you're talking about Materialized Views, then the View only exists as a query definition that is executed each time the view is accessed.... the data returned from the view query is not stored at all

Comment: There are different ways that a `VIEW` is performed and optimized, not a single way.  Without specifics, this discussion cannot go further.